# Angular 2 Change value of input placeholder via another placeholder after entring the value

Tags: angular, typescript, data-binding

I have an autocomplete input, i want to get the result from this input and put it on another input.

I'm trying this way

```
  <input placeholder="search for location" autocorrect="off"  autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="off" type="text" class="form-control" #search [formControl]="searchControl"  [(ngModel)]="title">
      </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Title</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" [(ngModel)]="location.title"    value="{{title}}"  name="title" required>
  </div>
```

With this code i only get what i write, but that's not what i'm looking to get, i want to get the final result after i pick from the autcomplete a value.

And want to get it on the title input.

Comment: How is the autocomplete implemented? I'm not seeing it

Comment: `<div class="form-group">
        <input placeholder="search for location" autocorrect="off"  autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="off" type="text" class="form-control" #search [formControl]="searchControl"  [(ngModel)]="title">
      </div>`

Comment: That's just a normal text field, I'm not seeing anything that makes this an autocomplete and thus cannot know how to make this work

Comment: the autocomplete is in the component.ts

Here is a gist if you want take a look https://gist.github.com/AlFalahTaieb/e2ca93514d0872cd8f89ed33fca68fdc

Comment: https://gist.github.com/AlFalahTaieb/e2ca93514d0872cd8f89ed33fca68fdc#file-add-location-ts-L79

Use this `place` variable, somewhere in this scope, set the value of the other input to whatever you want displayed from the selected `place` variable.

Comment: Could you please point me where i have to do the change?

Comment: I linked to a specific row, check it out.
Isn't that your code?>